# How can a background process know its own PID?

Tags: bash, process, background-process

I'm using bash on a RH Linux system.

Normally, you can get your own PID with the variable $$.  However, if a script runs one of its own functions as a background process - that doesn't work; all functions run in the background will get the PID of the parent script when $$ is used.

For example, here is a test script:

```
    /tmp/test:
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "I am $$"
    function proce {
      sleep 3
      echo "$1 :: $$"
    }

    for x in aa bb cc; do
      eval "proce $x &"
      echo "Started: $!"
    done
```

When it is executed:

```
    /tmp$ ./test
    I am 5253
    Started: 5254
    Started: 5256
    Started: 5258
    /tmp$ aa :: 5253
    bb :: 5253
    cc :: 5253
```

So - the parent script (/tmp/test) executes as PID 5253 and fires-off three background processes with PIDs 5254, 5256 and 5258.  But each of those background processes gets the value 5253 with $$.

How can these processes discover its actual PID?

Comment: Just a pedantic note: your example does not background the subshells, everything is done in the foreground.

Answer (score 10):

`$BASHPID` may be what you are looking for.

> BASHPID
>
> Expands to the process ID of the current Bash process. This differs from $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do
>   not require Bash to be re-initialized.

As opposed to `$$`

> ($$) Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it
>   expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables

Answer (score 6):

With `bash`:

```
echo "$BASHPID"
```

would give you the pid of the process that evaluates that `echo` command

Note that (for instance after a `enable -n echo`) it is not necessarily the same as the pid of the process that is *running* that `echo` command.

`bash` (or any shell) does its own soup with processes. It's not always useful to try and guess what process does what.

```
$ readlink -f /proc/self "/proc/$BASHPID"
/proc/30868
/proc/30747
$ (readlink -f /proc/self "/proc/$BASHPID")
/proc/30869
/proc/30869
```

In that second case, `readlink` is executed in the same process that interpreted the command line because that's the last command run in that subshell (so `bash` optimises out a `fork()`).

The `zsh` equivalent is in the `zsh/system` module:

```
$ zmodload zsh/system
$ echo $$ $sysparams[pid]
5155 5155
$ (echo $$ $sysparams[pid])
5155 30979
```

(`zsh` also exposes the parent pid of the subshell in `$sysparams[ppid]`).

Portably, you can do:

```
pid=$(sh -c 'echo "$PPID"')
```

All shells should run that `sh` as a direct child of the subshell interpreting that command line, so that `sh`'s `$PPID` should be that subshell.